# PowerShell stops executing commands/programs

Tags: powershell

Sometimes my PowerShell stops executing programs and I have yet to find out why. In this state, when I enter the name of an EXE file, the PowerShell immediately returns to a command prompt without executing anything. Cmdlets however appear to still work. There is also no error shown in the Windows event viewer or anywhere else I have looked.

I don't know how this state is triggered (I was developing a PS1 script the last time it happened), how I prevent it from happening, and how I can return to a working state without restarting my PowerShell.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem - if you find a solution, please do come back and answer your own question!

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. It happened to me a lot more when developing a script but only rarely during "normal" use, so I stopped caring. Everything I knew about the problem I posted into this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/f40881f9-e1a2-4548-8657-1d85ef5f3513

Comment: Thanks for coming back. We're getting bitten by it in TeamCity build steps, which is a bit of a pain - but very rarely when actually running scripts in the console. It's concerning though, as a lot of our infrastructure deployment relies on Powershell...

Comment: I have this problem a lot, too. In my case, it seems to be related to starting a Python process. Mercurial causes it to happen very rarely, but running our waf build seems to make it happen after 10 or 15 times.